# Laravel Forge performing query on migrate - which makes the migration fail

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, migration, laravel-forge

I'm trying to perform a migration with Laravel Forge to get the site up and running.

Laravel forge will perform `php artisan migrate --force` on deployment.
I can perform `forge@********:~/default$ php artisan migrate` when I'm trying to perform the migration via SSH.

Both are returning the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'MetiNet.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 2 limit 1)","file":"\/home\/forge\/default\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":625}}
```

So its performing a query on the database before the tables have been created, causing it to fail.

Bearing in mind, locally, the migrations work perfectly and this can't be replicated locally..how can I fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have to set an environment? Something like `php artisan migrate --env=prod`?

Comment: I've located the error. I had:

$user = User::find(2);
Auth::login($user);

I deleted this a long time ago. It seems that Forge wasn't updating from the repository correctly, so I've uninstalled it and hopefully this will work.

Thanks for getting back!